# What is wrong with this simple function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The output is "False". I cant figure out why...

Thanks

```
 def validate_pin(pin):
        if len(pin) == '4':
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
    
    
    
    validate_pin("1234")
```

Comment: len returns an int, you are comparing it to a string. you can see the same behaviour in the python terminal `4 == '4'` returns `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the length against the literal string `'4'` which is incorrect.

It should be int `4` without the quotes:

```
if len(pin) == 4
```